# data list to data matrix matlab/R

Tags: r, matlab, data-structures, matrix

I have a matrix of data which looks like:

```
date ticker return

2/1  MSFT   .21

2/1  GOOG   .11

2/1  CSCO   .09

2/2  MSFT   .22

2/2  GOOG   .19

2/2  CSCO   .15
```

and I want to transfer the structure to something like:

```
     MSFT   GOOG  CSCO

2/1  .21    .11   .09

2/2  .22    .19   .15
```

Is there an easy way to make this transfer in Matlab/R, other than run loops to get this?

Comment: Do you just want to print a table, or do you want this in some kind of data structure that you can then use for further purposes? Also, in what form is your matrix of data? A text file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `reshape2` library:

```
library(reshape2)

#sample data
dat <- data.frame(
    date = rep(c("2/1", "2/2"), each = 3)
  , ticker = rep(c("MSFT", "GOOG", "CSCO"), 2)
  , return = runif(6)
)

#Cast the data 
> dcast(dat, date ~ ticker, value_var = "return")

  date      CSCO      GOOG       MSFT
1  2/1 0.2555900 0.6212102 0.43078011
2  2/2 0.7092036 0.7013563 0.01225488
```

Answer (score 1):

and in matlab:

data as if loaded by textscan:

```
dates = {'2/1','2/1','2/1','2/2','2/2','2/2'}
sites = {'MSFT','GOOG','CISCO','MSFT','GOOG','CISCO'}
vals = rand(1,6);
```

reshaped:

```
[uDate,uiDate,ujDate] = unique(dates);
[uSite,uiSite,ujSite] = unique(sites);
sz = [length(uDate),length(uSite)];
valArray = vals(sub2ind(sz,ujDate,ujSite))
valArray = reshape(valArray,sz);
```

the value for '2/1' 'GOOG' is now in

```
valArray(find(strcmpi('2/1',uDate),1), find(strcmpi('GOOG',uSite),1))
```

not quite as elegant as R, but hey.   MATRIXMULTIPLY!

Comment: BlessedKey, thank you as well. But I think the line: "valArray = reshape(vals,sz);" should be changed to "valArray = reshape(valArray,sz);", right?

Answer (score 1):

FOR MATLAB CODE, THE CORRECT ONE SHOULD BE:

```
dates = {'2/1','2/1','2/1','2/2','2/2','2/2'}
sites = {'MSFT','GOOG','CISCO','MSFT','GOOG','CISCO'}
vals = 1:6;

[uDate,uiDate,ujDate] = unique(dates);
[uSite,uiSite,ujSite] = unique(sites);

sz = [length(uDate),length(uSite)];

positionIndex=sub2ind(sz,ujDate,ujSite);

[B,IX] = sort(positionIndex);

valArray = vals(IX);
valArray = reshape(valArray,sz);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in a more general case, if there were missing values:

dates = {'2/1','2/1','2/1','2/2','2/2','2/2'};

sites = {'MSFT','GOOG','CISCO','MSFT','GOOG','CISCO'};

vals = 1:6;

[uDate,uiDate,ujDate] = unique(dates);

[uSite,uiSite,ujSite] = unique(sites);

sz = [length(uDate),length(uSite)];

positionIndex=sub2ind(sz,ujDate,ujSite);

valArray=zeros(length(uDate),length(uSite));

valArray(positionIndex)=vals;

Answer (score 0):

The above solution for MATLAB won't work, if you have missing data in the original matrix that is hard to check before transformation.

In the DAVE's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17182489/163080) I would replace

```
valArray = vals(IX);
valArray = reshape(valArray,sz);
```

with

```
valArray = nan(sz);
valArray(B) = vals(positionIndex);
```

Missing values will be replaced by NaN.

---

R's `melt`/`dcast` are so much more elegant. Love it! I wish to have similar tools in MATLAB.